# How to show a * (asterisk) in Application Title when document has changed and is not saved

Tags: c#, mdi, editing, title

I have a MDI Application with one MDI child.

When a user changes a Textbox on the MDI child, the MDI child (= document) is changed and is not saved. I want this to be visible in the Titlebar of the Application, like this:

```
ApplicationName [DocumentName*]
```

When the users saves the Document and doesn't change anything after, it should display:

```
ApplicationName [DocumentName]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "document modified" flag. Then in your code that pulls out the document name to display in the title you can check this and if the document has been modified append "*".

Comment: Thanks. I thought there could be a function for, but I see I need to do it manually.